# How to get the id inside of a href

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried to get an id inside of a href. For example:

```
<a href="somerandomtext...id = #... some random text">
```

I am using python.

Tried to use `a_href = time.find('a', href=True).get("href")` and I got the href that has the id I want to get. I want to try to find the `#` and I tried to use instead of `.get("href")`, I used `.get("id")` but got nothing. How would I get the #?

Comment: Use `urllib` to parse the URL.

Comment: `.get('id')` gets the ID attribute of the `<a>` tag, it doesn't extract parts of the `href`. BS4 doesn't know anything about URLs, it just deals with HTML/XML.

Comment: What would you do with the parsed url though?

Comment: So it's actually part of the `href`?  It is not a separate `id` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`urllib.parse.urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) to parse the URL in `href`. This will allow you to extract the query string from the URL, and they you can use [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to parse the query string a dictionary.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

a_href = time.find('a', href=True).get("href")
qs = urlparse(a_href).query
id = parse_qs(qs)['id']
```